# need movement around z axis with coco3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

In my iOS app I have a 3D object created with cocos3d.
It's moving correctly around x and y axes. But it does not want to move around z!
Picture shows how it moves with the black arrows, and how it doesn't with red ones.

[image]

code from scene.m

```
-(void) touchEvent: (uint) touchType at: (CGPoint) touchPoint
{
    switch (touchType) {
        case kCCTouchBegan:
            break;
        case kCCTouchMoved:
            [self rotateMainNodeFromSwipeAt: touchPoint];
            break;
        case kCCTouchEnded:
            break;
        default:
            break;
}

// For all event types, remember where the touchpoint was, for subsequent events.
_lastTouchEventPoint = touchPoint;
}
#define kSwipeScale 0.6
-(void) rotateMainNodeFromSwipeAt: (CGPoint) touchPoint
{
    CC3Camera *camera = self.activeCamera;

    // Get the direction and length of the movement since the last touch move event,
    // in 2D screen coordinates. The 2D rotation axis is perpendicular to this movement.
    CGPoint swipe2d = ccpSub(touchPoint, _lastTouchEventPoint);
    CGPoint axis2d = ccpPerp(swipe2d);

    // Project the 2D axis into a 3D axis by mapping the 2D X & Y screen coords
    // to the camera's rightDirection and upDirection, respectively.
    CC3Vector axis = CC3VectorAdd(CC3VectorScaleUniform(camera.rightDirection, axis2d.x),
                              CC3VectorScaleUniform(camera.upDirection, axis2d.y));

    //CC3Vector axis = CC3VectorScaleUniform(camera.upDirection, axis2d.y);

    GLfloat angle = ccpLength(swipe2d) * kSwipeScale;

    // Rotate the node under direct finger control, by directly rotating by the angle
    // and axis determined by the swipe.
    [self.modelNode rotateByAngle:angle aroundAxis:axis];
}
```

Why it does not want to move around z axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to rotate the node around the Z-axis of the camera? If so, the `axis` that you are deriving above (which is the same as code from `CC3DemoMashUpScene`), uses the camera's `rightDirection` and `upDirection` to create an `axis` that is perpendicular to the Z-axis of the camera, by definition. The `rightDirection` and `upDirection` define a plane that is perpendicular to the direction the camera is pointing, so any linear combination of these vectors will result in a vector that lies in that plane.

To create rotation around the Z-axis, the `axis` must contain some Z component. The camera's `forwardDirection` can provide this Z-axis component. For the very simple example of rotating *only* around the camera's Z-axis, try setting the `axis` as:

```
CC3Vector axis = CC3VectorScaleUniform(cam.forwardDirection, axis2d.x);
```

or some combination of `axis2d.x` and `axis2d.y`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Bill. I'm a newbie in cocos so I'm sorry if I do something wrong. I need to leave current controls when I touch the node, and when I touch outside of it I want to rotate the node around z axis. Also is it possible to rotate the node around z axis if I move my finger around it (not just up and down but around my object, i.e. for node to follow my finger all the time 360 degrees)?

Comment: Here is a video showing how touches should affect the object. [link](http://youtu.be/8-wAg-Hgrpg) Is it possible?

Comment: There are several ways to handle this, and all have to do with determining that a movement is a rotation from the track the touches leave. You might want to use Gesture Recognizers to handle this. Specifically, UIRotationGestureRecognizer handles the familiar two-finger rotation gesture that is common to many iOS app UI's. And if you want to do it with a single finger, you might create a custom Gesture Recognizer.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Ended up using UIRotationGestureRecognizer.